# How to get the greek letter theta with R-Markdown with kable() in a table in the pdf?

Tags: r, unicode, kable

I want to let RMarkdown make a kable-table in my pdf containing some symbols (greek letter theta and a y with a tilde) given by a unicode. One of the symbols is indeed visible in the table, the other one is not.
What can I do to get them both visible?

I am fairly new to latex. I tried putting 4 back slashes in front of the unicode, because I know this workes when you want an ampersand sign in a string to be printed by kable to pdf. In this case, however, it did not work. Adding methode = "latex" to the kable function also did not work.

A small reproducible example:

YAML-header:

```
---
output:
   pdf_document:
     latex_engine: xelatex
---
```

Code chunk:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)

example <- tibble(symbol = c("\u03B8", "\u1EF9"))
example %>% kable()
```

The local output just below the chunk does display what I expect: the name of the variable, in the next line a theta symbol, and the line below a y with tilde symbol.
The output in the pdf does not show the theta symbol. It does show the y tilde symbol.
Anyone any suggestions to get them both in the pdf output? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing another document font could help. By using James (JD) Long's [solution](https://community.rstudio.com/t/greek-unicode-in-r-markdown/20870/4) posted on RStudio Community forum, I managed to get both theta and y with tilde on the same page. This required adding one line to the YAML header:

```
mainfont: Arial
```

I am sure there are also other fonts that would work.